# How can i specify in mining to only use 75% of my CPU power?

Tags: cpu-mining

I have seen when i mine Monero in pc, the cpu utilized goes to 95% to 100% most of the time, i want to keep it to 75 to 80%, what can i do?  will it work by specifying the threads? I have a 4 core pc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically if you have an AES-NI capable processor you will find the "sweet spot" at 1/2 the number of cores you have, so you won't ever be mining to 100% anyway. Right now we don't have a mechanism to throttle it beyond that, but we are working hard at that exact thing as part of the Smart Mining effort.

Answer (score 1):

For yam miner you can define how many cores will be mining with parameter "-t #"
where # is number of cores.
I have Pentium i5 and with 4 cores and -t 2 show me 80% utilization.